# Splitting string on conjoining words

Tags: c#

I am required to split few strings in arrays based on conjoining words i.e. on, in, from etc.

```
string sampleString = "what was total sales for pencils from Japan in 1999";
```

Desired result:

```
what was total sales

for pencils

from japan 

in 1999
```

I am familiar with splitting string based on one word but not multiple at the same time:

```
string[] stringArray = sampleString.Split(new string[] {"of"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're going to have more complex scenarios than that, like "What was the total sales of pencils from the Isle of Islay in 1999".

Comment: This isn't really a split per se.  A split would not include the conjoining words on which you split in the result strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this particular scenario you can use Regular Expressions to do this.

You will have to use something called a lookahead pattern, because otherwise the words you're splitting on would be removed from the results.

Here's a small [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) program that demonstrates:

```
void Main()
{
    string sampleString = "what was total sales for pencils from Japan in 1999";
    Regex.Split(sampleString, @"\b(?=of|for|in|from)\b").Dump();
}
```

Output:

```
what was total sales  
for pencils  
from Japan  
in 1999
```

But, as I said in the comments, it's going to be tripped up by things like the name of places that contain any of the words you split on, so:

```
string sampleString = "what was total sales for pencils from the Isle of Islay in 1999";
Regex.Split(sampleString, @"\b(?=of|for|in|from)\b").Dump();
```

Output:

```
what was total sales  
for pencils  
from the Isle  
of Islay  
in 1999
```

The regular expression can be rewritten like this to be more expressive for future maintenance:

```
Regex.Split(sampleString, @"
    \b          # Must be a word boundary here
                # makes sure we don't match words that contain the split words, like 'fortune'
    (?=         # lookahead group, will match, but not be consumed/zero length
        of      # List of words, separated by the OR operator, |
        |for
        |in
        |from
    )
    \b          # Also a word boundary", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace).Dump();
```

You might also want to add `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` to the options, to match "Of" and "OF", etc.